# Regex match only if a string is not present

Tags: regex

I want to match in regex if a particular string is not present,
for eg: the regex should match when the string is :

`"pool"`
`"pool play"`
`"poolplay"`

and not match when the string is :

`"car pool"`
`"car pool play"`

i was using something like:
`(?i)(pool(e|ed|ing)*)^(car+pool(e|ed|ing)*)` but need some help in perfecting it

Comment: What is the programming language? `(?i)\b(?<!\bcar\s)pool(?:ed?|ing)?\b` might work.

Comment: I am using Java 11

Comment: Then, to make the lookbehind contrained-width, you can also use `(?i)\b(?<!\bcar\s{1,100})pool(?:ed?|ing)?\b` (thus allowing up to 100 whitespaces between `car` and `pool`)

Comment: Just one whitespace is fine given the only scenario i wanna exclude is when car and pool appear in succession 

also  i also wanted to include cases when we have a string something similar to `crosspool` or just simple  `jcnpooljkv`

Comment: This is one of these times where using a single regex is probably not the best way to go. You end up with an unreadable regex, while checking for "car" separately is not an issue at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use

```
(?i)(?<!\bcar\s)pool(?:ed?|ing)?
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/3HAZUk/1). Add the word boundary `\b` after `(?i)` if the word you want to match starts with `pool`.

In Java, you can define the pattern with the following string literal:

```java
String regex = "(?i)(?<!\\bcar\\s)pool(?:ed?|ing)?";
```

*Details*:

- `(?i)` - case insensitive matching on
- `(?<!\bcar\s)` - no `car` as whole word + whitespace allowed immediately on the left
- `pool` - a `pool` substring
- `(?:ed?|ing)?` - an optional `e`, `ed` or `ing` char sequence.